# Why wont my ng-dirty update to my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a custom validation directive but everytime $scope.$watch updates the ngModel does not update if its been touched by the user

`console.log('value has changed', value);` shows the value updating

but

`ngModel.$touched` and `ngModel.$dirty` never change they are always the same, do i need to import them somehow to access and use them inside the directive

html

```
 <div validation-directive="validation-directive"        
    ng-model="company.fax_number">

 <input type="text" ng-model="company.fax_number"/>
 <span ng-hide="!validation.status">{{validation.status}}</span>

 </div>
```

javascript

```
module.exports = [
    '$log', function($log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attr, $ctrl, ngModel) {

                $scope.$watch($attr.ngModel, function(value) {
                    console.log('value has changed', value);
                    if (ngModel.$dirty) {
                        console.log('dirty', value);
                    }

                    if (ngModel.$touched) {
                        console.log('touched', value);

                     }

            });

        );
    },
    scope: true
};
}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use $attrs.ngModel.$dirty instead of ngModel.$dirty

Hope this helps.
regards!

Comment: sorry! and if you want capture focus lost from directive try this:
$element.on('blur', function() {
          //aweasome things
        });

Comment: I have added      console.log($attr.ngModel.$dirty) in the watch function, everytime i edit the field it logs 'undefined'  is it maybe because the directive is not on the input field itself ? is there a workaround that will keep my directive in the div and not in the input tag

Comment: Yes!, why not use <input type="text" validation-directive="validation-directive" ng-model="company.fax_number"/> ?

Comment: because the directive will loose scope on the span label `{{validation.status}}` which i need to update automatically with different error messages

Comment: Then you will have to create a template for your directive that includes the input and the span.